# JavaScript terminating all scripts running without throwing errors

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a company website, I have a page embedding JavaScript in such fashion:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="...">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="...">
  <script src="..."></script>
  <script src="..."></script>
  <script>
    ...
  </script>

  <script>
    /*
     * My block
     */
  </script>

  <script>
    ...
  </script>
  <script src="..."></script>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

The page is semi-managed by other teams in the company. The `<script>`'s before `My block` are hardcoded to load some of the prerequisite company-wide scripts. One of those scripts is jQuery. I can't change any of them because they are managed by another team. Due to some reasons, those scripts fail to load randomly sometimes. (Response codes can be 400, 404, 500, etc)

The scripts below `My block` have dependencies on the scripts above `My block`. So if the scripts on the top fail to load, the scripts at the bottom will throw out a lot of errors.

Inside `My block`, I am hoping to add a check to see if those scripts are loaded and running. (May be to check against jQuery?) If they are not loaded, I want to terminate all the loading/running of the scripts after `My block`, so the page will display a user-friendly message and doesn't throw a bunch of errors.

I wonder if this is possible?

Comment: The cleanest way might be just to redirect to a friendly error page, rather than trying to handle errors you have no control off.

Comment: You can do something like `if ($) ...` to see if jQuery was loaded, similar for other scripts I guess, depending on what they do. Blocking the remaining scripts without an error message can only be achieved by redirecting to another page

Comment: It's not the best solution, but anyway, you can just append innerHtml of the head tag, by scripts you need to load